# AMAZON Lex Missing credentials in config

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services

I use the html code from "https://aws.amazon.com/tw/blogs/machine-learning/greetings-visitor-engage-your-web-users-with-amazon-lex/" and I modify it to my amazon lex bots. But always reponose "Error: Missing credentials in config (see console for details)". Please tell me where should I correct? Thank you.

```
<head>
    <title>Amazon Lex for test</title>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.41.0.min.js"></script>
    <style language="text/css">
        input#wisdom {
            padding: 4px;
            font-size: 1em;
            width: 400px
        }

        input::placeholder {
            color: #ccc;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        p.userRequest {
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            min-width: 50%;
            max-width: 85%;
            float: left;
            background-color: #7d7;
        }

        p.lexResponse {
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-align: right;
            min-width: 50%;
            max-width: 85%;
            float: right;
            background-color: #bbf;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        p.lexError {
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            text-align: right;
            min-width: 50%;
            max-width: 85%;
            float: right;
            background-color: #f77;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:  left">Easy Join Chat Bot</h1>
    <div id="conversation" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; padding: 4px; overflow: scroll"></div>
    <form id="chatform" style="margin-top: 10px" onsubmit="return pushChat();">
        <input type="text" id="wisdom" size="80" value="" placeholder="Please enter a question or keyword.">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // set the focus to the input box
        document.getElementById("wisdom").focus();

        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region

        var lexruntime = new AWS.LexRuntime();

        var lexUserId = 'chatbot-demo' + Date.now();
        var sessionAttributes = {};

        function pushChat() {

            // if there is text to be sent...
            var wisdomText = document.getElementById('wisdom');
            if (wisdomText && wisdomText.value && wisdomText.value.trim().length > 0) {

                // disable input to show we're sending it
                var wisdom = wisdomText.value.trim();
                wisdomText.value = '...';
                wisdomText.locked = true;

                // send it to the Lex runtime
                var params = {
                    botAlias: 'EasyJoinChatBot',
                    botName: 'EasyJoinChatBot',
                    inputText: wisdom,
                    userId: lexUserId,
                    sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes
                };
                showRequest(wisdom);
                lexruntime.postText(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err, err.stack);
                        showError('Error:  ' + err.message + ' (see console for details)')
                    }
                    if (data) {
                        // capture the sessionAttributes for the next cycle
                        sessionAttributes = data.sessionAttributes;
                        // show response and/or error/dialog status
                        showResponse(data);
                    }
                    // re-enable input
                    wisdomText.value = '';
                    wisdomText.locked = false;
                });
            }
            // we always cancel form submission
            return false;
        }

        function showRequest(daText) {

            var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('conversation');
            var requestPara = document.createElement("P");
            requestPara.className = 'userRequest';
            requestPara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(daText));
            conversationDiv.appendChild(requestPara);
            conversationDiv.scrollTop = conversationDiv.scrollHeight;
        }

        function showError(daText) {

            var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('conversation');
            var errorPara = document.createElement("P");
            errorPara.className = 'lexError';
            errorPara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(daText));
            conversationDiv.appendChild(errorPara);
            conversationDiv.scrollTop = conversationDiv.scrollHeight;
        }

        function showResponse(lexResponse) {

            var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('conversation');
            var responsePara = document.createElement("P");
            responsePara.className = 'lexResponse';
            if (lexResponse.message) {
                responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lexResponse.message));
                responsePara.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
            }
            if (lexResponse.dialogState === 'ReadyForFulfillment') {
                responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                    'Ready for fulfillment'));
                // TODO:  show slot values
            } else {
                responsePara.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                    '(' + lexResponse.dialogState + ')'));
            }
            conversationDiv.appendChild(responsePara);
            conversationDiv.scrollTop = conversationDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MV05gMQMnZnIiO5NUeIv1rMLp5PYSuvMDAlBqFfc0jM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code the sdk is asking for credentials, you need to configure it right in config,credentials and bash profiles.

Comment: @Juke I put my config.py on google doc. Can you tell me where should I configure?

Comment: check here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-set-up-cli.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure Cognito to get AWS Temporary credentials back. This can be done as follows:

```
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    // Provide your Pool Id here
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:XXXXX',
    });
```

Once you add this, you can use your lex application on a browser-side JavaScript client.

Answer (score 0):

Install AWS CLI for your system. After this in "C drive"  => go to "Users" =>  "YourName" , There would be a folder created as ".aws" . That folder would have created a file named "credentials".

Check if the
**aws_access_key_id,
aws_secret_access_key,
aws_session_token**

are present there.